# How create friendly url in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, url-routing

How create friendly url in Flask?

What would be written in the route

/

And the user received(Url is constructed by categories from the database)
       /machines/cars/modern/Lexus LX570

Is it possible to do this and how to write this?

**Solution1:**

Redirect 302

```
/product/<int:id_product> redirect to second route(get in databases) /machines/cars/modern/Lexus LX570
```

**Solution2:**
Three url and one function for get id product and other data of database

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    #use function for get data in database

@app.route('/<productName>')
def product(productName):
    #use function for get data in database


@app.route('/<path:fullPath>/<productName>')
def product_with_categories(fullPath,productName):
    #use function for get data in database
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50484197/edit) your post and elaborate what you are trying to do, and what the outcome you wish to have, and your entire route setup.

Comment: I'm trying to guess what you want, maybe [Flask Variable Rules](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#variable-rules) is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
from flask import make_response, url_for, redirect, abort

@app.route('/<int:id_product>')
def product(id_product):
    # Load you path with id_product to get nice url (in database)
    if id_product == 123:
        path = '/machines/cars/modern/Lexus LX570'
    else:
        abort(404)
    return redirect(url_for('product_friendly_url', product_category_hierarchy=path))

@app.route('/<path:product_category_hierarchy>')
def product_friendly_url(product_category_hierarchy):
    # Retrieve product from his product_category_hierarchy (in database)
    product_item = {'id': 123, 'product_category_hierarchy': product_category_hierarchy, 'blabla': 'test'}
    return make_response(str(product_item))
```

Call `/123` in your browser will redirect (302) you to '/machines/cars/modern/Lexus LX570' and print :

```
{'id': 123, 'product_category_hierarchy': 'machines/cars/modern/Lexus LX570', 'blabla': 'test'}
```

Comment: Im sorry, badly expressed

Me need
/<int:idProduct>

From the database I will take synonyms of categories.
Should be like this for user
/machines/cars/modern/Lexus LX570

Comment: @Tarmor Can you edit you question and add more details ? What is the final url you need ? `/machines/cars/modern/Lexus LX570/123` for example ?

Comment: Start - 
/<int:idProduct>

We take the data(categories product) from the database

End  -  
/machines/cars/modern/Lexus LX570

Comment: @Tarmor I just updated my answer, take a look ;)

Comment: That is, implement through synonyms as in Drupal. A convenient option for development, but bad for SEO (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: It's not so bad for SEO, but you can only use friendly url and never the url with id and redirection if you want. You can also look about "mod_rewrite" for Apache or for other http server (more complicated but more powerful), store like Magento use this technique.

Comment: Very thank! Sorry, accidentally rewrite you post instead of his

Comment: Don't worry, I just reject your edit ;)